# JMS message consuming after functionality completes

Tags: jms, consumer

After consuming messages from a queue using a `MessageListener` it's immediately not getting another message from queue. It is waiting until my functionality completes and then another message is coming from the queue. How do I get messages from queue quickly without depending on my functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the `onMessage()` method of your `MessageListener` implementation is executing all of your "functionality" and that's why message consumption is slower than you'd like since the `onMessage()` must complete before consuming another message.

There are a number of ways to address this problem (in no particular order):

- Use a Jave EE application server with MDBs. MDBs are pooled so they can process multiple messages concurrently.
- Use Spring JMS's `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` which can consume messages concurrently.
- Implement your own `MessageListener` pooling using a pooling library like [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/).
- When your `MessageListener` receive a message acquire a thread from a thread pool and process the message in that thread allowing the `MessageListener` to receive messages more quickly. The only real problem I see with this approach is that it limits how you can acknowledge the message. In short, you should acknowledge the message *before* passing it to the new thread.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain third point _Implement your own MessageListener pooling_ and how to acheive with Own message Listener.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. I don't really have more detail than that. If you want to get into specifics about how to implement your own pooling you'd really need to start a new, specific question.